# SQL: Insert into alias a <br> to have the column name with 2 lines

Tags: sql, openoffice.org

I'm working in OpenOffice Base, that is similar to Access.
I have a table (Costs) with the following columns (each month has 2 values(paid and pending):

- Provider
- Januarypay
- Januarypend
- Februarypay
- Februarypend
- Marchpay
- Marchpend
- Aprilpay
- Aprilpend
- Maypay
- Maypend
- Junepay
- Junepend
- Julypay
- Julypend
- Augustpay
- Augustpend
- Septemberpay
- Septemberpend
- Octoberpay
- Octoberpend
- Novemberpay
- Novemberpend
- Decemberpay
- Decemberpend

I'm trying something like this

```
Select "provider",**"NEEDHELPHERE"**,(select (Januarypay + Januarypend + Februarypay + Februarypend + Marchpay + Marchpend + Aprilpay + Aprilpend + Maypay + Maypend + Junepay + Junepend + Julypay + Julypend + Augustpay + Augustpend + Septemberpay + Septemberpend + Octoberpay + Octoberpend + Novemberpay + Novemberpend + Decemberpay + Decemberpend) as TotalYear from "Costs")
```

Replace **"NEEDHELPHERE"** for the following code (I put this, otherwise this would be too long):

```
Januarypay as "January" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Paid",Januarypend as "January" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Pending",Februarypay as "February" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Paid",Februarypend as "February" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Pending",Marchpay as "March" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Paid",MarchpendMarchpay as "March" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Pending",Aprilpay as "April" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Paid",AprilpendAprilpay as "April" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Pending",Maypay as "May" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Paid",Maypend as "May" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Pending",Junepay as "June" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Paid",Junepend as "June" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Pending",Julypay as "July" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Paid",Julypend as "July" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Pending",Augustpay as "August" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Paid",Augustpend as "August" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Pending",Septemberpay as "September" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Paid",Septemberpend as "September" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Pending",Octoberpay as "October" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Paid",Octoberpend as "October" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Pending",Novemberpay as "November" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Paid",Novemberpend as "November" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Pending",Decemberpay as "December" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Paid",Decemberpend as "December" || char(10)|| char(13) || "Pending"
```

The result of the query should be something like this:
[image: sql result example]

**Table info**

[image: table info]

**Table sample data**
[image: sample data]

Comment: what is your table info and what about your data? can you show some detail

Comment: In MySQL command line it can be done as "January\nPaid", and in Oracle SQL*Plus it can be done as "January|Paid".  However these do not work in LibreOffice Base.  Perhaps it is not possible.